# ArcPy - Dividing every raster cell value by the maximum cell value

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I want to divide every cell of a raster by the raster's maximum cell value using ArcPy. Here is what I have done so far.

```
densityRaster = LineDensity(shapefileName, None, "", "", "")
maxVal = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(densityRaster ,"MAXIMUM")
normalRaster = densityRaster/maxVal #maxValue i get is 5.66
```

This gives me an error described below. Anybody has clues to where I get it wrong?

> Runtime error : ERROR 000732: Input
>   Raster: Dataset 5.666 does not exist or is not supported

If I enter `normalRaster = densityRaster/5.666`, I get the correct result.

Comment: On a side note, you should be able to get the maximum value by accessing the `maximum` property from your `densityRaster` since it's a [`raster`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) object.

Comment: @dmahr - nice tip! i would try that..i have just put my feet into arcpy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `type(maxVal)`, you'll notice that it's neither a number or string. As a matter of fact, it is a ArcPy [result object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000).

In order to extract that information use `.getOutput(0)`. You can cast it to whatever type (int,float,etc) if you want as well.

Comment: you are damn right! i didn't check the type..i can get it to work with float(maxVal[0]) now..

Comment: +1 I didn't know it could be accessed like that actually. I thought you had to use `.getOutput(0)`. Honestly, I don't know why some tools return a result object and not just the actual result.